# How do I force TypeScript to check against all union members?

Tags: typescript, union-types, recursive-type

So I have this piece of code and it works pretty well:

```js
interface A {
  type: "a";
  payload: { isDisabled?: boolean };
}

interface B1 {
  type: "b1";
  payload: { children: A[] };
}

interface B2 {
  type: "b2";
  payload: { child: B | null };
}

type B = B1 | B2;

const items: B[] = [
  {
    type: "b2",
    payload: {
      child: {
        type: "b1",
        payload: {
          children: [
            {
              type: "a",
              payload: {
                isDisabled: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
```

tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

The problem arises when I (for example) replace `isDisabled: false` with `isDisabled: 1234`. I expect the error to be:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Instead, I get this:

```
Type '"b1"' is not assignable to type '"b2"'.

Type '{ children: { type: "a"; payload: { isDisabled: number; }; }[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ child: B | null; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'children' does not exist in type '{ child: B | null; }'.
```

It seems like TypeScript *excludes* `B1` from `B` and tries to check `items[0].payload.child` against `B2` only (ignoring `type: "b1"`).

There are a couple of workarounds, though:

1. Declare `B2['payload']` as `{ child: B }`. Omitting `null` fixes the aforementioned behaviour. Unfortunately, this is not really an option, because I want `child` to be nullable.
2. Another workaround is to use some other type instead of `null` in `B2['payload']['child']`. Unfortunately, the only types that do seem to work there are empty tuple (`[]`) and empty object (`Record<string, never>`), and I would really like to use a primitive value.
3. Setting `strictNullTypes: false` in tsconfig also works, but this is not appropriate for obvious reasons.
4. Finally, it is possible to use type assertion: `const items: B[] = [ ... ] as B[];`. This seems redundant, it is very easy to forget to add it and it is also very hard to verify (using a linter, for example).

So, the question is: is it possible to make TypeScript respect `B1` and report the expected error without relying on any of the aforementioned workarounds?

Comment: Your issue is primarily with the error message, right? The compiler certainly *checks* against all union members (if it didn't, you'd see much weirder behavior, such as the compiler rejecting a valid `B1`, which it doesn't).  Your problem is that the displayed error message is not the one you were expecting; this is probably not something easily addressed, since the error display is a heuristic choice with unions.

Comment: If `T` is not `X | Y` then it's not `X` and it's also not `Y`, and the compiler has to choose `X` or `Y` to talk about in the error message (or else error messages would be HUGE). You were thinking `Y` but the compiler described the problem with `X`.

Comment: Kind of looks like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40934 ... will keep looking (but I don't think there's going to be a good fix for you other than for you to accept suboptimal error messages)